# Deserializing a specific column

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, deserialization

UPDATE: I removed some print_r & echo tests I had above the loop and I was able to view the data.

Am fetching everything from a table with the following query.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM campaign_manager ORDER BY 'date'") or die(mysql_error());
```

I have a loop that displays everything in a table.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    // echo out the contents of each row into a table
        echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . $row['campaign_id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['paragraph_id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['que_id'] . '</td>';
        echo "</tr>"; 
}
```

So far pretty straight forward so far... Here's where it gets tricky.

The $row['paragraph_id'] is serialized. I ran a test to get the data to appear how I need it to as follows;

```
$do = mysql_fetch_array($result);
print_r(implode(", ",unserialize($do['paragraph_id'])));
```

Which prints out the data exactly how I need it to. But how do I implement that into my while loop? I've tried several variations with all being failure. I've tried saving into variables outside and inside the loop. I've also tried deserializing in each row iteration. Nothing seems to work and the rows will not show up in the table.

How can I get the data from that table to display using that while loop while deserializing that one column?

Comment: You have an error in your query syntax: `SELECT * FROM campaign_manager ORDER BY 'date'` it should be: `SELECT * FROM campaign_manager ORDER BY \`date\`` using backticks, not single quotes right now the `order by` clause does not work.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. Unfortunately, even after removing the ORDER BY it doesn't fix my main issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use print_r with option true like

```
print_r(implode(", ",unserialize($do['paragraph_id'])), true);
```

or simple

```
echo '<td>' . implode(", ",unserialize($do['paragraph_id'])) . '</td>';
```

Comment: Andrew, Thank you. It was my error. I had some print_r/echo code above my loop that was breaking it.

Answer (score 0):

```php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    // echo out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . $row['campaign_id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . 
          print_r(implode(", ",unserialize($row['paragraph_id'])), true) 
       . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['que_id'] . '</td>';
    echo "</tr>"; 
}
```

Comment: @Daniel you sure you have something in `$row`? do a `var_dump($row);` in the while loop

Comment: Yes, if I print_r($row); It outputs: 

Array ( [0] => 6 [id] => 6 [1] => 23 [campaign_id] => 23 [2] => a:1:{i:0;s:2:"22";} [paragraph_id] => a:1:{i:0;s:2:"22";} [3] => 0 [que_id] => 0 )

So I know the data is in there. Something about the while() in combination with deserializing the column breaks the output. I even tried outputting the row with serialized data.